# For loop is printing backwards when it shouldn't be, Any input on solution?

Tags: c, for-loop

I am trying to print the customer number and sales arrays incrementally "1-4" & "1000-4000" for final project. Instead it is printing out "4-1" & "4000-1000". Any input on what I'm doing incorrectly?

```c
    printf("How many customers do you want to track?\n");
    scanf("%d", &ctracked);

        while((ctracked!=0)&&(ctracked--))
        {
        printf("Enter customer number. ");
        scanf("%d", &cnumber[ctracked]);
        printf("Enter the sales for the customer ");
        scanf("%d", &csales[ctracked]);
        }

    printf("Sales for the Customer\nCustomer Customer\n");
    printf("Number   Sales\n");

    for(counter=0; counter<ALLOWED_RANGE; counter++)
    {
        printf("%d        %d\n", cnumber[counter], csales[counter]);
    }

    totalsales = csales[0] + csales[1] + csales[2] + csales[3];
    avgsales = totalsales / (float)4.0;
    printf("\nTotal sales are $%d\n", totalsales);
    printf("Average sales per customer is $%.2f", avgsales);
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger to step through the code that accepts the inputs, and watch the value of `ctracked` (or just read the code carefully).

Comment: Change your while loop go from 0 to ctracked, and your problem will solved.  Something like this: int i = 0; while (i < ctracked) { scan your stuff ; i++}.

Comment: Well, at least we can teach him that `while((ctracked!=0)&&(ctracked--))` can be simply written as `while(ctracked--)`... and **always check the return** of EVERY user input function.

Comment: @keep_learning thanks that worked perfectly. much love g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your while loop, "while((ctracked!=0)&&(ctracked--))" with the below code.

```
for(counter=0;counter<ctracked;counter++)
{
    printf("Enter customer number. ");
    scanf("%d", &cnumber[counter]);
    printf("Enter the sales for the customer ");
    scanf("%d", &csales[counter]);
}
```

Comment: That does work but tne of requirements of code is using a while loop to get user input. I am trying: int x = 0; while(x<ctracked) {scan iput; x++} as people have said but that causes exe to crash half way thru